# How to read CSV file having empty columns in java and few columns with only some data?

Tags: java, csv, stream

I have my Test.csv file like below,Now i want to read the csv file (Using JAVA) by skipping empty columns if any.
If total column is comming as empty then i want to skip that column

```
111, ,John,2000,   ,US 
222, ,Alle,3000,   ,China
333, ,Kite,4000,LCD,IND
444, ,King,5000,LED,Aust

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            Scanner s = null;
            try {
                s = new Scanner(new File("D:/sri/Test.txt"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = s.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here Iam able to read empty columns also.Could you please suggest regarding this

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to using SuperCSV with CsvBeanReader,you could custom a CellProcessor to ignore line when data is empty.
[SuperCSV document](https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_reading.html)

A simple solution is using CsvReader and read line by line, then check each data after parser. Once you get an empty string, then move to next line!
[CSV Reader Document](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html)

Comment: I want to insert that type of csv files in DataBase dynamically. Some times it may contains empty columns some times not.How can i achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a util method to check if it is empty string or not.

```
public static boolean isBlank(String str) {
        int strLen;
        if (str == null || (strLen = str.length()) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
            if ((Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)) == false)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and use it in your reader like below

```
Scanner s = null;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new File("D:/sri/Test.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] line = s.nextLine().split(",");
            for (String element : line) {
                if (!isBlank(element))
                    System.out.println(element);
            }

        }
```

Comment: I also want to insert that data in DB (by skipping only empty columns),then how could I achieve that ?